# Silverlight 4 + RIA deployment problem!

Tags: silverlight, entity-framework, wcf-ria-services

I created a silverlight 4 application which uses RIA and EntityFramework to connect to a db. This application works flawlesly in my development machine but once deployed on the server. I get this error :

Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.

> at
>   System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Client.WebDomainClient`1.BeginQueryCore(EntityQuery
>   query, AsyncCallback callback, Object userState)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Client.DomainClient.BeginQuery(EntityQuery
>   query, AsyncCallback callback, Object userState)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Client.DomainContext.Load(EntityQuery
>   query, LoadBehavior loadBehavior, Action`1 callback, Object userState)
>   at CDSUniformDesign.MainPage.MyProjectDesignsLoad_Completed(Object
>   sender, EventArgs e)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Client.OperationBase.Complete(Exception
>   error)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Client.LoadOperation.Complete(Exception
>   error)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Client.DomainContext.CompleteLoad(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Client.DomainContext.<>c_*DisplayClass1b.b*_17(Object
>   )

The server is a dedicated Windows 2003 R2. I uploaded the sources to the server and run at there without any problem (In Visual Web Developer 2010). I checked the "svc" url from my browser and it seems to be working as well.

I'm really having a hard time to understand the cause of this, anybody can help me?

Thanks,

Özden

Comment: I remember having a hard time to deploy a RIA services/Silverlight project to my hosting environment. Though I didn't have the same error as you, this blog post helped me fix some issues: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/saurabh/archive/2010/03/16/ria-services-application-deployment.aspx Maybe it's worth checking it out.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to install the [WCF Ria Services](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=cd3191a1-def4-4caa-8120-1f0bbcf4bb05&displaylang=en) on your server.

Install it using the command prompt: **msiexec /i RIAServices.msi SERVER=true**

**Update:**
[Brad Severtson](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bradsevertson/archive/2011/02/17/a-guide-to-deploying-ria-services-solutions.aspx) provides a guide to deploy RIA Services Solutions.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. The server already had that installation and I un-installed than installed with the command prompt you gave but still get the same error.